# Intersection of two quadratic equations with two variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have two quadratic equations with two variables. Basically I just want to find the point of intersection between the two curves. How should I proceed with the solution?

The equations are $(4x)^2-(9p)^2+ 16x+52=0$ and $x^2+2x+3p-23=0$. Thanks! Your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I corrected it. It's supposed to be -(9p)^2

Comment: Two such equations will, in general, have four points of intersection, so you expect a quartic equation. You can obtain $3p$ in terms of $x$ from the second equation, and substitute in the first to eliminate $p$, obtaining a quartic for $x$.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I realized a while ago that I could express both equations in terms of x and equate those two. But your solution is more direct. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the second equation $p = \frac{23-x^2-2x}3$. Substituting in the  first equation we get,

$16x^2-9(23-x^2-2x)^2+16x+52=0$, giving you a quartic equation equivalent to

$-9x^4-36x^3+394x^2+844x-4709=0$ which would produce four values of $x$ and corresponding values for $p$. The equation can be solved on a calculator online and you can also look for the method to solve a quartic equation if you want to do it by yourself.